# A question about the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem

The question is:
$g:R\rightarrow R$ has at least three bounded continuous derivatives and let $X_i$ be $iid$ and in $L^2$. Prove that:

i) $\sqrt{n}[g(\overline{X_n}) - g(\mu)]\xrightarrow{w} N(0,g^{'}(\mu)^{2} \sigma ^2)$ and that

ii) $E[g(\overline{X_n})-g(\mu)] = \frac{\sigma^2g''(\mu)}{2n} + o(n^{-1})$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

where $\overline{X_n} = \frac{\sum X_n}{n}$, $\mu = EX_1$, $\sigma^2=Var(X_1)$

I have proved i) using CLT but for ii) $g(\overline{X_n}) - g(\mu)\approx N(0,g^{'}(\mu)^{2} \sigma ^2/n)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Since $RHS$ has $g''(\mu)$, I was thinking of expanding $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2g'(\mu)\sigma^2/n}}$using Taylor's series at $\mu$ but it already has $g'(\mu)$ in it which is a constant. If it had a $g'(x)$, I would get a $2^{nd}$ derivative, so not sure how to approach the problem. Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: Are you tacitly assuming the $X_i$ are iid, so the $\overline X_n$ obeys the CLT?

Comment: Yes, $X_i$ are $iid$.

Comment: Are you also tacitly assuming the $X_i$ are in $L^3$?

Comment: No, $X_{i}\in L^2$ but $g$ has at least $3$ bounded continuous derivatives as stated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variation on the other answer.  It has two parts.

First, writing the Taylor approximation as $$g(x)=g(\mu)+g'(\mu)\,(x-\mu) + g''(\mu)\,(x-\mu)^2/2 + (x-\mu)^2h(x-\mu)$$ where $h$ is continuous and bounded, and vanishes at $0$.  (This should be clear from the usual Taylor expansion error bound for $x$ near $\mu$; and from the boundedness of $g$: one has $h(x)=(g(x)-(g(\mu)+g'(\mu)\,(x-\mu) + g''(\mu)\,(x-\mu)^2/2)/(x-\mu)^2$, which is clearly bounded when $x$ is far from $\mu$.)

Second, write  $Z_n = \sqrt n(\overline X_n-\mu)$, so $Z_n\to Z$  in distribution, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$, by the usual CLT.

Now the error term in the original problem's (ii) is $$E\left( Z_n^2 h(Z_n/\sqrt n)\right) / n$$ and the problem boils down to showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty} E\left( Z_n^2 h(Z_n/\sqrt n) \right)= 0$.

Since the $Z_n$ converge in distribution to $Z$ there exist random variables $Y_n$ with the same distribution as $Z_n$ such that $Y_n\to Z$ with probability 1.  (Such as, $Y_n = F_n^{-1}(\Phi(Z))$ where $F_n$ is the cdf of $Z_n$ and $\Phi$ is the cdf of $Z$, or by Skorohod's theorem.) Since $Y_n\to Z$ w.p.1 and $EY_n^2 = EZ^2$, the sequence $Y_n^2$ is uniformly integrable.  This, plus   $h$ being bounded, implies  the sequence $Y_n^2 h(Y_n/\sqrt n)$ is uniformly integrable.

(For details of the uniform integability: Hewitt and Stromberg theorem 13.47, for instance implies the convergence $Y_n^2\to Z^2$ holds in $L^1$, and exercise 13.39 then gives uniform integrability of the $Y_n^2$.  See also Theorem 21 in Dellacherie and Meyer, *Probability and Potential*, 1978 edition, p."23-11".)

So $$\lim_{n\to\infty}E(Y_n^2 h(Y_n/\sqrt n)) = E (\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n^2 h(Y_n/\sqrt n))  = E Z^2 h(0) = E(Z^20) = 0.$$  But $Z_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same distribution, so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}E(Z_n^2 h(Z_n/\sqrt n)) = \lim_{n\to\infty}E(Y_n^2 h(Y_n/\sqrt n)) = 0,$$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me take some time to read and get back.

Comment: Fair enough.  I always find uniform integrability arguments tricky.

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late reply! Just making sure if $h$ being bounded follows from $g$ being bounded and also I didn't understand why $h(0)=0$. Invoking UI is very interesting. Is it also a known result that if $EY_n^{2} = EZ^2$ and $Yn\xrightarrow{w.p.1} Z$, then $Y_n$ is UI? Because I am just aware of standard definition, you know if $Sup_n E(|Y_n|1_{|Y_n>y|})\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow 0$. Thanks and appreciate your time.

Comment: @manifolded  I have tried to answer these questions in an edit to my answer .  I think UI gets short shrift in analysis classes, as it seems technical and boringly nerdy.  I remembered that it is the big brother of the dominated convergence theorem: you don't actually need a common dominating function but only just UI.  Then I scoured old textbooks to see how to fill in the details of the argument.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, yes UI is definitely powerful and I should look for more opportunities to apply it. I will look at those references too, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment than an answer, but at least an idea.

Using Taylor's formula with integral remainder gives 
$$
g\left(\overline{X_n}\right)-g(\mu)=\left(\overline{X_n}-\mu\right)g'(\mu)
+\frac{\left(\overline{X_n}-\mu\right)^2}2g''(\mu)+\frac 12\int_\mu^{\overline{X_n}}g^{(3)}(t)\left(\overline{X_n}-t\right)^2\mathrm dt.
$$
Therefore, taking the expectations reduces us to show that 
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\mathbb E\left[\int_\mu^{\overline{X_n}}g^{(3)}(t)\left(\overline{X_n}-t\right)^2\mathrm dt\right]=0.
$$

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I will try to prove the $limit$ now.

Comment: It has to be subtle, because if you replace $g^{(3)}(t)$ in the integral with a constant upper bound, as you may, and as you might be tempted, you get a cubic polynomial in $\overline X_n$, whose expectation is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, I was stuck there because I felt obligated to use $g^{(3)}(t)$ is bounded.